# Why doesn't onStopJob be launched?

Tags: android

I use the following code to start a repeated task,  I think that `logError("OnStop")` will be launched after I invoke `stopScheduleRestore`.
But in fact, `logError("OnStop")` doesn't be launched, why?

```
class RestoreService : JobService() {

    override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters): Boolean {
        logError("OnStart")

        Thread(Runnable { completeJob(params) }).start()
        return true
    }

    override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters): Boolean {
        logError("OnStop")
        return false
    }


    fun completeJob(parameters: JobParameters) {
        logError("OK")
        jobFinished(parameters, false)
    }

}


fun startScheduleRestore(mContext:Context){  
    val mJobScheduler = mContext.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
    val jobInfo = JobInfo.Builder(mContext.getInteger(R.integer.JobID), ComponentName(mContext.packageName, RestoreService::class.java.name))
                        .setPeriodic(interval)
                        .setPersisted(true)
                        .build()

    mJobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo)
}


fun stopScheduleRestore(mContext:Context){
    val mJobScheduler = mContext.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
    mJobScheduler.cancel(mContext.getInteger(R.integer.JobID))

}
```

Comment: are you cancelling job before its started?

Comment: No, first I invoke startScheduleRestore, then I invoke stopScheduleRestore

Comment: But your job is periodic. So the job might not be started before you called stopScheduleRestore